# NSArray from MySQL to NSTableView

Tags: mysql, objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, nstableview

First of all, I'm new to objective-c programming so I've probably made some mistakes in my code.

Here's what I've done : I've created a php file with some xml to get values from my MySQL database. Everything goes into a NSArray in objective-C. If I look at the log, everything works fine because it shows my arrays with every MySQL rows and columns like this:

```
2012-04-02 08:20:14.822 POS[64632:707] (

    {
    CPU = 0;
    TPS = "(null)";
    TVQ = "(null)";
    consigne = 0;
    coutantQuantiteRecue = 0;
    description = "";
    nom = "";
    prixProduit = 0;
    quantiteRecue = 0;
    stock = 0;
},
    {
    CPU = 768;
    TPS = "(null)";
    TVQ = "(null)";
    consigne = 0;
    coutantQuantiteRecue = 0;
    description = "";
    nom = hhh;
    prixProduit = 0;
    quantiteRecue = 0;
    stock = 0;
},

2012-04-02 08:20:14.836 POS[64632:707] The number of rows is:2
```

The problem is that the only thing I get in my TableView is `{` in each cell like this:

[image: Table View example image]

Here's my .h :

```
@interface InventoryManagement : NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource>
{
IBOutlet NSTableView* inventoryTable;
NSArray* m_items;

}
-(int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)inventoryTable;
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)inventoryTable objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)rowIndex;
-(void)dealloc;

@property (retain) NSArray* m_items;

@end
```

And here's my .m file :

```
@implementation InventoryManagement

@synthesize m_items;

-(id)init
{
[super init];

NSInteger index = 0;
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/php/getProducts.php?index=%d&", index];
m_items = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
NSLog(@"%@", [m_items description]);
[m_items retain];
[inventoryTable reloadData];
return self;
}



-(int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)inventoryTable
{

NSLog(@"The number of rows in fullResult is:%i", [m_items count]);
return [m_items count];



}

-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)inventoryTable objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)rowIndex
{

return [m_items objectAtIndex:rowIndex];

}

-(void)dealloc
{
[m_items release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

My object is well-connected to dataSource and delegate of my TableView. I want those cells to be filled by my database values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Cocoa Bindings for future works. They are great.

Regarding your question: the problem is in the method

```
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)inventoryTable objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)rowIndex
{

return [m_items objectAtIndex:rowIndex];

}
```

You are returning the whole object, that is:

> {
>       CPU = 768;
>       TPS = "(null)";
>       TVQ = "(null)";
>       consigne = 0;
>       coutantQuantiteRecue = 0;
>       description = "";
>       nom = hhh;
>       prixProduit = 0;
>       quantiteRecue = 0;
>       stock = 0; }

which is a string.
You have to check the tableColumn variable and return only the right information: e.g. quantiteRecue, CPU, etc..

The best way to do this is to create a Model class in ObjectiveC which wraps a row of your db. Then your m_items array will contains your Model class, and you can return the right property without parsing every time the string...

Comment: You're right. I didn't realize it. I'm gonna give it a try and post my result later. Thanks!

Comment: What I actually did is create a "for" loop and insert each column cell into a string[] and another loop to insert those strings into an array[].